# Socket.io client served from CDN

Tags: socket.io

According to the Socket.io documentation:

> A standalone build of socket.io-client is exposed automatically by the socket.io server as /socket.io/socket.io.js. Alternatively you can serve the file socket.io-client.js found at the root of this repository.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io('http://localhost');
    socket.on('connect', function(){
    socket.on('event', function(data){});
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
  });
</script>
```

However, I would like to serve the socket.io client from a separate CDN (it's cheaper, faster, and reduces load on my server).

How can I do this?  Do I have to disable the socket.io default?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As long as the version of the client you are using is the same as what you use on your server, there should not be any problem serving it from a CDN.

That said, the client is tiny (24kb), and if caching is setup properly, this should have very little impact on your server.

update: as mentioned by @maxwell2022, socket.io has its own cdn starting with 1.0.0, so you can use:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: From version 1.0, socket.io offers to serve the client from their CDN:  http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#cdn-delivery

Comment: wait, is there a separate socket.io lib for the client code than the server code?

Comment: yes, the client code is different from the server code.  It even has its own repo https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client

Comment: must have been down.  Works fine now.  There are newer versions than 1.0 now, though.  You may also use the ones on cloudflare, see https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io

Comment: The CDN URL of the current version can be found [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io).

Comment: It appears from the [socket.io blog](https://socket.io/blog/socket-io-1-4-5/) that v1.4.5 and newer no longer use cdn.socket.io. Instead, they use [CloudFlare](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io) as the CDN.

Answer (score 15):

You can find [here](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io/) CDN links to the socket.io client script files.

### 0.9.16

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js
```

### 0.9.6

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.6/socket.io.min.js
```

...and so on.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the wiki](http://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/How-do-I-serve-the-client), if you choose to serve the client yourself, you can clone the [socket.io-client](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client) repository and look at the `dist/` subdirectory. There are 4 files to serve (this may change):

- `WebSocketMain.swf`
- `WebSocketMainInsecure.swf`
- `socket.io.js`
- `socket.io.min.js`

Just make sure you update these files whenever you update the server.